# Getting an array of arrays from a POST operation into a GO calculation through reqBody and json unmarshal

Tags: arrays, json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

Client currently has an app with calculations running in the browser in JS. The calculation function takes in financial inputs like incomes, expenses, and does a number of calculations, before drawing some pretty graphs and making some sensible suggestions.

I want to change it over to be a GO API because we're going to need ever more complex calculations and older mobile phones really don't like the task of all those calculations.

But I am having problems getting the specific input fields out of the input data in GO.

At the moment the inputs are an array of arrays so like [income1, income2, expense1, expense2 and so on..

Each of the input or expense elements is itself an array. So they're like this.

```
[["Michael J Mouse", "Monthly", "Wed, 12 May 2021 10:59:07 GMT", "2500", "No", "Mon, 11 May 2026 10:59:07 GMT"],
["Michael J Mouse", "Monthly", "Wed, 12 May 2021 10:59:07 GMT", "2500", "No", null], 
....and then on to the other items.
```

Incomes have names, frequencies, start dates, amounts, they may end or not, and might have been given an end-date or not (users, eh!) And similar for expenses.

I can POST the long inputs array to a GO API with JSON stringify so it gets to the API fine. I can echo it back with a fPrintf.

But when I try to unmarshal it I end up with no commas and no quotes. So it's impossible to tell where one piece of input ends and the other starts.

```
[[Michael J Mouse Monthly Wed, 12 May 2021 10:59:07 GMT 2500 No Mon, 11 May 2026 10:59:07 GMT] [Michael J Mouse Monthly Wed, 15 May 2021 14:29:07 GMT 2500 No <nil>]
```

That's the reqBody I get when I pull the data into GO. That seems to be the problem already...no quotes, no commas.

Then, when I unMarshal I get each section between the square brackets as an individual element like this.

```
[Michael J Mouse Monthly Wed, 12 May 2021 10:59:07 GMT 2500 No Mon, 11 May 2026 10:59:07 GMT] 
[Michael J Mouse Monthly Wed, 12 May 2021 10:59:07 GMT 2500 No <nil>]
```

Now I can go back and rewrite everything so that the clients POSTs the data with names on each field and then define structs....but I wonder if there's any way of getting something like this just into an array...then I have already have the code for all the rest.

```
["Michael J Mouse", "Monthly", "Wed, 12 May 2021 10:59:07 GMT", "2500", "No", "Mon, 11 May 2026 10:59:07 GMT"]
```

Am I missing something really simple?

This is the code:

```
func doCalcuation(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
// get the body of our POST request
reqBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
fmt.Println("got to this stage: doCalcuation")
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%+s", string(reqBody))
fmt.Println("This should be then the reqBody")
fmt.Println(len(reqBody))
var datas []interface{}
json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &datas)
fmt.Println("this is after the unmarshalling")
fmt.Println(datas)
```

Comment: *"But when I try to unmarshal it I end up with no commas and no quotes. So it's impossible to tell where one piece of input ends and the other starts."* -- That's just how it's printed by `fmt.Println`.

Comment: I don't know what to do with that...

Comment: I don't particularly care. I'm just using what I see on the terminal output to help me write the code, to convert a function from JS. To figure out what I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fmt.Println, won't be showing "," between each element of array if you want to print it that way you need to format and print it

```
    var datas [][]string

    json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &datas)
    fmt.Println("this is after the unmarshalling")

    array := []string{}

    for _, data := range datas {
        array = append(array, fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", strings.Join(data, ",")))
    }

    output := fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", strings.Join(array, ","))

    fmt.Println(output)
```

Comment: Now I feel silly. I've been trying to solve a problem that isn't there and - as a result - not getting anywhere. Thanks!

I don't want to print it...just using print like I'd use console.log in JS...to debug as I go. 

As long as I can get at the contents, I'm fine.

Comment: Indeed...very silly of me. As soon as I stopped thinking that the commas had vanished, I can process the data no problem. 

Again, thanks.  

That's what you get jumping between languages!